# Use return variable from a function or st.session_state

Tags: python, pandas, caching, methods, streamlit

I am learning Streamlit framework along with Python. My question is related to code design. I am using functions to apply transformations to pandas dataframes and returning variables to pass it to another functions or display to the user. On the other hand, i can achieve the same result using st.session_state, assigning the "return" function variable to the st.session_state dictionary which provides access to this variable throughout the code like a global variable. So what´s the right pythonic or streamlit way to pass variables ?

```
def some_function (dataframe):
   a = do some transformation
   return a

st.dataframe(somefunction())
```

or

```
def some_function (dataframe):
   a = do some transformation
   st.session_state['a'] = a
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a multipage app, it's probably a good idea to use `st.session_state` or `st.cache_data` to avoid to reload your whole data or keeping some information persistent across each rerun.

There is no real guidelines for that. However, you should read these 2 advanced features:

- [Caching](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching)
- [Add statefulness to apps](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried multiple pages approach but i stick with module streamlit-options. In the case of multiple pages app i guess it's the only way to use cached data.